# How to convert a png file from from 600 x 800 into 600 x 400?

Tags: conversion, png

Get info on my source  png file.

```
file  old.png
old.png: PNG image data, 600 x 800, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

I want to convert old.png from 600 x 800  into  600 x 400.

```
convert -resize 600x400  old.png  new.png
```

Check my output.

```
file new.png
new.png: PNG image data, 300 x 400, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 0):

convert -resize 600x400!  old.png  new.png